# How to directly assign a std::vector to another std::vector when the elements have the same type but different constness?

Tags: c++, iteration, constants, shared-ptr, qualifiers

I have some types like the following:

```
struct Order_t;
using SpOrder_t = std::shared_ptr<Order_t>;
using CpOrder_t = std::shared_ptr<const Order_t>;
using SomeOrders_t = std::vector<SpOrder_t>;
using ConstOrders_t = std::vector<CpOrder_t>;
```

I want to directly assign from a `SomeOrders_t` to a `ConstOrders_t`, but the compiler said those are different types:

```
SomeOrders_t _cur_ords;

ConstOrders_t TradingOrders() {
    return _cur_ords;
};
```

Is there a method to let me assign directly? Or do I have to use a loop and assign them one by one?

Comment: We need a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Add the necessary `#include`'s and the complete error message.

Comment: `std::vector<SpOrder_t>` and `std::vector<CpOrder_t>` are different(& unrelated?) types. How exactly do you want the conversion to happen?

Comment: `SomeOrders_t` and `ConstOrders_t` are two unrelated types. What is the *actual* problem you need to solve? Why do you think a solution like the one shown would solve that problem?

Comment: They are a different types. But you can do `constOrders = { some.begin(), some.end() };` https://godbolt.org/z/49h6nE9ac so conversion is done more explicitly (still there is implicit conversion from `CpOrder_t` to `SpOrder_t`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `T` is a template with one type parameter, and `u` and `v` are different types, then `T<u>` and `T<v>` are different (and unrelated) types.
Even if there is an implicit conversion from `u` to `v`, there is no (default) implicit conversion from `T<u>` to `T<v>`.
(`std::shared_ptr` has converting constructors and assignments that enable the conversion from `shared_ptr<Order_t>` to `shared_ptr<const Order_t>`, which makes them behave like `Order_t*` and `const Order_t*`.)

Making the conversion explicit is pretty trivial, though:

```
ConstOrders_t TradingOrders() {
    return { _cur_ords.begin(), _cur_ords.end() };
};
```

Comment: nitpicking: "..then T<u> and T<v> are different (and unrelated) types"  they can be related, its just not implicit / automatically provided. Actually `std::shared_ptr` does support conversiosn between compatible pointer types for construction and assigment. `std::vector` only in a rather limited way via its range constructors

Comment: with c++23 you will be able to do `ConstOrders_t TradingOrders() { return {std::from_range, _cur_ords}; };`

Comment: @0xbachmann Does it have any benefit?

Comment: @molbdnilo not necessarily in this example but it allows you to construct a vector from any range (range being more loose than an iterator pair of the same type)

Answer (score -3):

The definition of a [`shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) is declared as:

```cpp
template<class T>
std::shared_ptr<T>
```

Defining `T` as `const _T` or `_T` generate two different type (if you wan't to see how it work check this [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates)), but you can actually change the type by casting it using [`static_pointer_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast). In your case it would look like:

```cpp
SomeOrders_t _cur_ords;

ConstOrders_t TradingOrders() {
    return static_pointer_cast<const Order_T>(_cur_ords);
};
```

Comment: Most of the time using a cast for any reason is not a really good idea, except of course you can't do it any other way, for example when generating a pointer from a dynamicly loaded library. The use of this kind of features are most of the time related to a wrong design.

Comment: `_cur_ords` is a vector, how do you want to `std::static_pointer_cast` it? `std::static_pointer_cast` works on `std::shared_ptr` and not on `std::vector`

Comment: Using casts to work around constness (correctness) is a violation of a design contract. Never do this.